# Kerberos Authentication with Team Explorer Everywhere in CentOS

Tags: linux, kerberos, team-explorer-everywhere

I am having a problem with authenticating from team explorer everywhere.  I run kinit myusername and a cache file is created in /tmp.  An attempt to get gives me the following:

```
> tf get myproj -recursive
Access denied connecting to TFS server http://[removed] (authenticating as mydomain\myusername)
```

It then asks for my username.  I give it the same domain and username that just failed and it accepts.  I checked the log file below.

```
more teamexplorer-clc-2014.10.11-11.22.03.log 
2014-10-11 11:22:03,990 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /opt/TEE-CLC-12.0.0/native/linux/x86/libnative_console.so from user-specified directory
2014-10-11 11:22:04,374 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /opt/TEE-CLC-12.0.0/native/linux/x86/libnative_misc.so from user-specified directory
2014-10-11 11:22:04,867 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.loader.NativeLoader) Loaded /opt/TEE-CLC-12.0.0/native/linux/x86/libnative_auth.so from user-specified directory
2014-10-11 11:22:04,871 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.jni.natives.NativeAuthMethods) Loaded GSSAPI library: libgssapi_krb5.so
2014-10-11 11:22:04,876 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.commands.Command) Using default credentials (supported and available)
2014-10-11 11:22:05,009 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.httpclient.DefaultHTTPClientFactory) HttpClient configured for http://[removed], authen
ticating as logged in user
2014-10-11 11:22:07,556 ERROR [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) Negotiate Scheme did not provided token
com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException: Negotiate Scheme did not provided token
        at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.auth.NegotiateScheme.authenticate(NegotiateScheme.java:284)
        at com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.auth.AuthorizationHeaderScheme.authenticateHost(AuthorizationHeaderScheme.java:34)
        [removed]
        at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.Application.run(Application.java:149)
        at com.microsoft.tfs.client.clc.vc.Main.main(Main.java:34)
2014-10-11 11:22:07,625 INFO  [main] (com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector) Failure authenticating with NEGOTIATE @[removed]
```

See also, [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91450db5-3d36-4275-9ec8-7ab35013c258/teeclc-kerberos-regression?forum=tee).  The profile command does not appear to be available to my tf.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that team explorer everywhere had the wrong server.  Somehow, when it asked for authentication at the command line it was successful.  In any case, the problem had nothing to do with Kerberos.  When I fixed the server name (using tf workspace -new -s:server workspace), it stopped asking for credentials.